# Handling in-app purchases with multiple bundle ids

Tags: ios

I use multiple schemes in my app that have different bundle IDs associated with them for different environments. For example, I have:

- Production: com.myapp.ios
- Staging: com.myapp.ios-staging

I have enabled in-app purchases but realised that I can't use the in-app purchases in my staging environment because that's not the one that's on App Store Connect. Therefore it's returning zero products when I try to retrieve them.

I have a storekit config profile but I can't use that for the bulk of my testing because of the need to verify receipts on my server.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a fake app in App Store Connect that uses my Staging bundle id.